# Blender crashes (gets stuck) on viewport render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view

I've been working on a project for some time. And I heavily used the rendered shader in the viewport for it.

However I enabled the option that saves all textures within the blend.ini file and since then my blender crashes whenever I try to enable the viewport rendered shader.

Even after disabling it again it still crashes.

Does anyone know what i'm dealing with?

Comment: From the File menu Load Factory Defaults and the File Import and try importing components of the original .blend file. Keep importing more until you hit the issue.